Cant install on Angular 18
I cant install ng-bootstrap 17.0.0 on Angular 18.1.3.
I tried ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap but throw error:
PS X:\mediacar\angular\MLMessageApp> ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
√ Determining Package Manager
› Using package manager: npm
√ Searching for compatible package version
› Found compatible package version: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@17.0.0.
√ Loading package information from registry
√ Confirming installation
× Unable to install package
> ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap                 
√ Determining Package Manager
  › Using package manager: npm
√ Searching for compatible package version
  › Found compatible package version: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@17.0.0.
√ Loading package information from registry
√ Confirming installation
× Unable to install package

npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm error
npm error While resolving: mlmessage-app@0.0.0
npm error Found: @angular/core@18.1.3
npm error node_modules/@angular/core
npm error   peer @angular/core@"18.1.3" from @angular/animations@18.1.3
npm error   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm error     peerOptional @angular/animations@"18.1.3" from @angular/platform-browser@18.1.3
npm error     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm error       peer @angular/platform-browser@"18.1.3" from @angular/forms@18.1.3
npm error       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm error         peer @angular/forms@"^18.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@13.7.0
npm error         node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
npm error         2 more (ngx-bootstrap, the root project)
npm error       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm error     peer @angular/animations@"^18.0.1" from ngx-bootstrap@18.0.2
npm error     node_modules/ngx-bootstrap
npm error       ngx-bootstrap@"^18.0.2" from the root project
npm error     1 more (the root project)
npm error   peer @angular/core@"18.1.3" from @angular/common@18.1.3
npm error   node_modules/@angular/common
npm error     peer @angular/common@"18.1.3" from @angular/forms@18.1.3
npm error     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm error       peer @angular/forms@"^18.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@13.7.0
npm error       node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
npm error         @ng-select/ng-select@"^13.7.0" from the root project
npm error       2 more (ngx-bootstrap, the root project)
npm error     peer @angular/common@"18.1.3" from @angular/platform-browser@18.1.3
npm error     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm error       peer @angular/platform-browser@"18.1.3" from @angular/forms@18.1.3
npm error       node_modules/@angular/forms
npm error         peer @angular/forms@"^18.0.0" from @ng-select/ng-select@13.7.0
npm error         node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select
npm error         2 more (ngx-bootstrap, the root project)
npm error       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
npm error     5 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
npm error   9 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"17.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@18.2.0
npm error node_modules/@angular/core
npm error   peer @angular/core@"18.2.0" from @angular/forms@18.2.0
npm error   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm error     @angular/forms@"^18.1.0" from the root project
npm error     peer @angular/forms@"^18.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@17.0.0
npm error     node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm error       @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"17.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-14T17_20_33_610Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-14T17_20_33_610Z-debug-0.log


This question is similar to: How do I read npm "conflicting peer dependency" error messages?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user2871030 issue not reproducible stackblitz Demo -> cd test -> npm i
